# Starting FTP with xinetd

Tags: ftp, xinetd

I'm using GNU's Inetutils FTP and have gotten it all set up except it does not automatically start when I turn on my system. In order to get it to work I have to start the standalone using "ftpd -D". I've figured out that I have xinetd running and I believe I need to use that to automatically start the daemon.

In the /etc/xinetd.d/ directory I've added a file named 'ftp'. Inside its contents are:

```
service ftpd
{
    socket_type = stream
    protocol = tcp
    wait = no
    user = root
    server = /usr/bin/ftpd
    instances = 20
}
```

**Doing a whereis shows that ftpd resides in /usr/bin/ftpd**

After adding it I reloaded the configuration and restarted the server.

```
/etc/init.d/xinetd reload
/etc/init.d/xinetd restart
```

My xinetd.conf file is as followed:

```
# Simple configuration file for xinetd
#
# Some defaults, and include /etc/xinetd.d/

defaults
{
    instances           = 60
    log_type            = SYSLOG authpriv
    log_on_success      = HOST PID
    log_on_failure      = HOST
    cps                 = 25 30
}

includedir /etc/xinetd.d
```

There was also an inetd.config file in my system so I added the following for good measure though it doesn't seem inetd is running.

```
ftp     stream  tcp     nowait  root    /usr/bin/ftpd   in.ftpd -l -a
```

When I try to connected to my ftp server I get the error "**ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server**". Does anyone have any idea why this isn't getting started automatically by xinetd?

*I got my information from this website:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-how-do-i-configure-xinetd-service/*

Comment: Are you sure `inetd` (or `xinetd`) is running and not reporting errors when it starts? Connection refused would seem to indicate that it isn't. Also, use `lsof` to see if it's listening on the FTP port.

Comment: Using 'ps -ef | grep xinetd' shows that it is started, though I don't see it logging anything. (root      1625     1  0 22:28 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/xinetd -pidfile /var/run/xinetd.pid -stayalive)

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that `sytemd` changes things, AFAICT, with regards to how the `vsftpd` process gets forked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Incase anyone else has this problem in the future, I forgot to specify a port to use for the service, changed the service name to ftp and set disable to no. Here is my final service file:

```
service ftp
{
    port = 21
    disable = no
    socket_type = stream
    protocol = tcp
    wait = no
    user = root
    server = /usr/bin/ftpd
    instances = 20
}
```

To get the logging working I used the following command:

```
/usr/sbin/xinetd -filelog /var/log/xinetd -f /etc/xinetd.conf
```

Comment: For anyone coming in much later usually port and protocol for common servers are defined in /etc/services.  If that file is missing in some custom distro like Yocto, usually the package is called netbase.

Answer (score 1):

service (ftp)=> you can see the service name on c:/services file please check

```
{
    port = 21
    disable = no
    socket_type = stream
    protocol = tcp
    wait = no
    user = root
    server = /usr/bin/ftpd
    instances = 20
}
```

Comment: `c:/services` ??

Comment: si, servicios! Claro